# Button on click ... else

Tags: button, onclick

I have this code with a button:

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i>
</a>
<ul id="ma-mobilemenu" class="mobilemenu nav-collapse collapse" style="display: none;">
<li><?php echo $_menu ?></li>
</ul>
```

When the button is clicked I'd like to use this other code:

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i>
</a>
<ul id="ma-mobilemenu" class="mobilemenu nav-collapse collapse" style="display: block;">
<li><?php echo $_menu ?></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a programming question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use jquery to do your job:**

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<i class="fa fa-align-justify">Link/Button</i>
</a>
<ul id="ma-mobilemenu" class="mobilemenu nav-collapse collapse" style="display: none;">
<li>Menu</li>
</ul>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn").click(function(){
    if(($(".mobilemenu").css("display"))=='none'){
        $(".mobilemenu").css("display","block");
    }else{
        $(".mobilemenu").css("display","none");
    }
})
});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

if you click the link `<a></a>` it will change `<ul></ul>` display none to block.

Comment: @GennaroSantoro may be you are doing something wrong. wait i am sending total script

Comment: Just last question... after click it's work fine.. If I like to have with another click the dislpay to none?

Comment: Very Nice.. thanks again!.. it's work fine, but when put the link to jquery.min.js , another script in the page doesn't work :(((

Comment: @GennaroSantoro use jquery 1.10.2

Comment: ok. i'm trying to change jquery version from your script (always conflict) and from other script..

Comment: @GennaroSantoro my script will support almost all versions of jquery. Since it is not using any deprecated function. may be you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @GennaroSantoro My script is supporting jquery 1.2.6 to latest 2.1.4

Comment: your script work fine with all version i tryed.. but the other script(it use 1.11.0) always broken

Comment: @GennaroSantoro are you adding 2 jquery script? use only 1.11.0 which will make all script compatible.

Comment: There are jquery script in template and in some extensions installed... is impossible for me..

Comment: @GennaroSantoro add a `;` at the end of my script. since you are using more than one script. hope your issue wiil be solved. Check updated answer

Comment: nothing change.. your script still to work.. the other no..  if i put in the page i'm working only <script src.... > and i cancel all the rest.. the other script doesn't work..

Comment: @GennaroSantoro can you please post the total page where you are trying to add my script

Comment: I posted.. there is another way without jquery?